# new array that contain emails that appear in both arrays

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays that contain emails addresses. I would like to create a new array that contain only the emails that appear in both arrays.
is there any function that do that?

I tried to use "array_intersect_assoc". no good...

```
$newGroupsArray = array_intersect_assoc ($firstArray , $secondArray);
```

Comment: why the `_assoc()` variant, maybe you just need plain `array_intersect`

Comment: @Rizier123 - imagine 2 arrays with email addresses....

Comment: Why should you show us that arrays. What imagine??

Comment: Because its just array....nothing special...

Comment: If it's "just array, nothing special".... then why `array_intersect_assoc()` instead of `array_intersect()`

Answer (score 0):

yes use a foreach array and the in array function
something life

```
$array1
$array2
$array3
  foreach (array1 as $a){
   if (in_array( $a, $array 2){

        array_push($array3 , $a);
    }
   }
```

array 1 and 2 are your email arrays, this will go through every item in array 1, and check if it is in array2 with the in array function, if it it , it'll put it in array 3.
the code is roughly written so probably won't work as a copy and paste but that is one way you can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = ["hello","hey","ola"];
$b= ["hey","bye","tata"];
var_dump(array_intersect($b, $a));
```

OP:
`array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "hey" }`

Answer (score 0):

[array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-intersect.php)

remember the order of the params **MATTERS**